# CPU fan suddenly at 100%

Tags: cpu, bios, fan, cooling

yesterday evening my CPU fan started to do crazy stuff.
Currently it only knows "normaly working" and "100%".

For the system, it is a quite new medi-core system, configured/build by myself and worked like a charm for 2 month.

The interesting system parts:

- Mainboard: Asus M5A97 Evo R2.0 AMD 970 So.AM3+
- CPU: AMD FX-Serie FX-6300 ( Boxed )
- Cooler: Scythe Katana 4 ( replaced box fan/cooler
  unit )

What I did:

- SpeedFan/Hardwaremonitor - try to set fan speed manually
- Enable/Disable Cool'n Quiet
- Manually set fan speed in Bios ( not working )
- FW mainboard update/flash ( not that I thought it would help, bc. system ran fine before an the changelog had nothing about fan controls in it )

As I said earlier, the FAN has 2 modes:
normal mode, everything works normal, can set Fan speed by software/bios and cool'n quiet works together with win 7.

and 100% mode, wich starts without any specific reason. Plus a restart or/power off/on does not solve the 100% CPU Fan.
In 100% mode I am not able to control the fan speed whatsoever ( speed fan/ asus speed/ bios... )

Sometimes it goes to normal for no specific reason ( system was unzipping a 25gb file and it went to normal, system was idle on win desktop and it went to 100% FAN again )

CPU stress was never above 50% and even while using a prime/stresstest it never went above 45 deg ( normal/100% fan mode - in normal it slowly climbs up to rpm max... )

The CPU tempretature looks "good", BUT it seems to be to low. GPU/Chasis temprature display reasonable values ( 20-30 deg ) but CPU temprature is around 10 deg - when my room temprature is around 20 deg... and as I did not build a peltier element into my pc - that is strange.

Plus, if the regulation would work correctly the fan should nearly stop/ 0 rpm on me.

So, I am wondering: is the fan simply broken? Or do I need to check CPU/Mainboard issues as well?

Currently I hope for a broken fan and try to replace it with the boxed/bad fan that was in the package until a replacement is delivered.

Comment: Have you tried BIOS update or changing temperature threshold on BIOS configuration?

Comment: @emirjonb yes, as stated above I updated the mainboard firmware. Any setting of threshold/manual override and so on is only working in "normal mode", if it goes to its 100% mode, it wont listen to any of those values

Comment: how many pins does the fan have 3 or 4?

Comment: has a 4 pin pwm - correctly connected ... and worked for over month, even during the recent heatwave and around 30-40 room temp.

Comment: I think you should try a new fan, you can use your boxed AMD fan, and a BIOS restore to Default (just in case)

Comment: that was my hope ( did not have the time yesterday evening ). Bios was reset to defaults after the update just to be sure. Can the fan be the cause for such behav.? worried that the mainboard is telling the fan to go nuts... but yeah, should try it out with the boxed

Comment: Are you running Win10? Recently my machine's fan has gone crazy.  I noticed that wlanext.exe was running at high CPU.  Then I found this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-networking/wlanextexe-using-25-of-cpu-fan-on-high/ea2ff9f3-681c-456a-a390-a5ebe7f450a1  That was my problem. I killed the process just to see and the fan slowed down.  If it isn't that process it could be another.